# MongoDB Design - Benefits of Using Unique Indexes vs. Using _id to Enforce Uniqueness of Field

Tags: mongodb

I have a question on the current best practices when enforcing uniqueness of a field in MongoDB.

As an example, let's say I'm using signing up users, and I want to enforce that each user needs to have a unique email address. I have 3 options (#3 is not mutually exclusive with the others):

1. Override `_id` field to be the email address
2. Create a unique index on an `emailAddress` field, leaving the `_id` field unchanged (and unused)
3. Ensure the API checks for duplicates before inserting into the database in the `emailAddress` field

I am thinking that #3 is essential regardless of #1 and #2, but what else should I do?

Should I also override the `_id` field to be the email address (#1) because I don't need 2 unique fields, or should I create a unique index on `emailAddress` and leave the `_id` field as is (#2)? Maybe neither?

What are the benefits/downsides to each options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Override `_id` field to be the email address

If email address is unique and will never change, using email as `_id` saves you an extra field and index (so some small amount of storage and overhead). However, since `_id` is immutable changing an email address would require more work: copy and insert the current document with new `_id`, then delete the document with the original email address.

> 2. Create a unique index on an `emailAddress` field, leaving the `_id` field unchanged (and unused)

This is best if you need to enforce a unique email address but might allow your users to change it in future. The `_id` field is not unused in this case: it is still the primary key to uniquely identify a document.

> 3. Ensure the API checks for duplicates before inserting into the database in the `emailAddress` field

This isn't needed in either of the first two scenarios. Inserts/updates with a unique index will throw a duplicate key exception which your API will have to handle.

If you *don't* have an index enforcing unique email addresses this check is also not reliable: with concurrent clients a duplicate email address could be added in the time between when a client checks for existence and the insert/update operation happens.

Answer (score 1):

leave _ID alone.  #3 is an app decision as to whether it is critical your app only have unique emails - it has nothing to do with indexing - and how you might reject a duplicate email attempt whether valid or error is only about the personality of your app.

your indexes should be set based on your query needs.  they do not have to be unique. i.e. an index on State...think forward on how the queries are going to be happening and plan your data schema & indexes accordingly.... in NoSQL the indexing is very key...

for uniqueness consider a combo key of 2 fields...